# WPF Dictionary Binding failure is very slow

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have most of the `Label` objects in my app bound such that they can be replaced from a webservice.

I store my replacements in a Dictionary.  The replacements vary based on the Client that loaded for the app.

The problem I am having is that most of the time I don't replace the labels, and the binding failure is throwing an exception that is very slow.

Here is an example:  *(Note this code functions correctly, it is just slow if it can't find a match.)*

```
<Label Content="_Gender"
       Helpers:CaptionHelper.PropertyName="Content"
       Helpers:CaptionHelper.PropertyValue="{Binding Labels[Gender], 
                                                     FallbackValue=_Gender}"
       Target="{Binding ElementName=cbGender}" />
```

When the binding tries to lookup Lables[Gender], I get this in my output window:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 17 : Cannot get 'Item[]' value (type 'String') from 'Labels' (type 'Dictionary`2'). BindingExpression:Path=Labels[Gender]; DataItem='MyViewMV'
      (HashCode=63776763); target element is 'Label' (Name=''); target property is 'PropertyValue'(type 'String') TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 
           Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 
           The given key was not present in the dictionary.
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Params Truncated)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Params Truncated)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Params Truncated)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(Params Truncated)
   at MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(Params Truncated)'
```

Since I have a lot of these, it is taking about a full second to run through them all.

Is there a way to make the binding not throw an exception when the dictionary look up fails?  Or somehow fail quicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the option to, I would change your `IDictionary` implementation to one that returns `null` and instead use `TargetNullValue` (or even be `IDictionary<TKey, object>` and return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` if you still use `FallbackValue`):

```
public class PassthruDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> instance;

    // ... other stuff

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (instance.TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return default(TValue);
            }
        }
        // ... more
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this too old for a clarifying question, but here it goes:  I can't seem to find a way to return DependecyProeprty.UnsetValue.  Say I have a `PassthruDictionary<string,string>`, how can I return UnsetValue?  (It compiles but throws a run time exception for me.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the speed can be improved dramatically if you do not run the code in a debugger. Actually the printing of the stackteace in Visual Studio is *by far* the slowest part. If you run your application without a debugger attached, I am pretty sure the performance loss will not be noticable anymore.

I had a similar problem where we were catching an exception inside a library and even if you do that VS will print a note about a first chance exception being caught in code, every time the exception is being caught (and handled). The exception was triggered about 50 times at the startup and it took the application like 10 seconds to startup and all just because of the console logging. Once I ran the application without a debugger it started up almost instantly.

So maybe trying to workaround that exception is just premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Actually, all this does is disable the output in the VS output pane. It doesn't actually speed things up.

ORIGINAL:

I had a similar problem, but I wanted to catch and log the errors. However, you can use the following solution to simply disable outputting the errors to the VS2010 output window. The solution comes in 2 parts, the first is a simple class:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace DevBindingErrors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Intercepts all binding error messages. Stops output appearing in VS2010 debug window.
    /// </summary>
    class BindingTraceListener: TraceListener
    {
        private string _messageType;

        public override void Write(string message)
        {
            // Always happens in 2 stages: first stage writes "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :" or similar.
            _messageType = message;
        }

        public override void WriteLine(string message)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", _messageType, message));
        }
    }
}
```

The 2nd part is in App.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows;

namespace DevBindingErrors
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            PresentationTraceSources.Refresh();
            PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add(new BindingTraceListener());
            PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Switch.Level = SourceLevels.Warning;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to ignore all binding errors, just comment out the `Debug.WriteLine(...)` line. (I wouldn't really recommend this though) This will speed up execution as well, without losing the ability to debug the application.

The idea for this solution came from [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2006/09/14/wpftracesources.aspx), which has more details on trace sources in WPF too.

Comment: You could just not define TRACE.