# Why can't I have a type Constraint of Object

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to setup custom IDictionary that will allow `Object` as my TValue.

Here is what it looks like:

```
public class NullTolerantDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
             : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
            else
            {
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

When this compiles it says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'TValue'.

So to fix this I change my type constraint to be like this:

```
where TValue : object
```

(`object` instead of class)

I then get this message:

> Constraint cannot be special class 'object'

**How do I get around this?**

Extra credit for explaining why `object` is not able to be a constraint.

Comment: Every `TValue` being an `object` doesn't imply every `object` being a `TValue`. I suspect you need to cast `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` to `TValue`.

Comment: Because it's pointless:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644703/c-sharp-generics-constraining-t-where-t-object-doesnt-compile-error-constr

Comment: Note that "cannot implicitly convert" does not mean "cannot convert".  You can convert the reference explicitly by casting, as long as you know that the object returned by UnsetValue is in fact a TValue instance: `return (TValue)DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`

Comment: For extra credit: `Object` cannot be a type constraint because it's already an implicit type constraint.  We already know that any instance of the type parameter will inherit from Object.  That's why you can call `ToString()`, `GetType()` and `GetHashCode()` on variables whose type is an unconstrained type parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem here is not with generic type argument constraints but with the signature of the indexer.

The indexer is documented to always return a `TValue`, *whatever that happens to be*. The `else` branch however tries to return `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, which is of type `object`. Since not all `object`s are `TValue`s, the compiler complaints ("no implicit conversion").

It would make no difference if you placed any number of constraints on `TValue`, and even if you could constrain it to `object`. The type argument could still be set to anything more derived than `object` and `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` would still not be convertible to that type.

If you want to achieve such an effect you could use a `public static` read-only property such as

```
public class NullTolerantDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
         : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public static TValue MissingValue { get; private set; }
}
```

and return that from the indexer, presumably so that it can then be used in reference comparisons.

But that would still leave open the question: how do actually get a `TValue` value to use as `MissingValue`? You could place the `new()` constraint on `TValue` and create an instance inside a static constructor, but that would decrease the possible applications for this class. This results in the design starting to get a bit clunky to use, and since that's exactly what you are trying to avoid there's not much point in going that way.

Comment: You are exactly right.  I am going to change it to just return `default(TValue)`.  It is a bit less precise, but it will work good enough and not get in to the issues of trying to make my type params more than they can be.

Comment: @Vaccano default(TValue) will return null; why not just `return null;`?

Answer (score 5):

> Why is object not able to be a constraint? And how do I get around this?

You don't. And you don't need to. All managed types in .NET can be cast to `object`. There are a few things that can't (unmanaged pointers, etc), but they are not compatible with generics anyway.

The real problem is, I guess, that `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` is `object`. Well.... that isn't a `TValue`. Imagine `TValue` is `int` or `byte`: there are no "unset" values of an `int` or `byte`. You cannot return an arbitrary `object` for such a `TValue`.

Frankly, I would just have your caller use `TryGetValue` directly, and not use this extension method. You *could* do something like returning a dummy class instance with a `TValue`, or returning `null` - but frankly the caller can *just call `TryGetValue`* to achieve the same thing more conveniently.

Comment: The reason that I am not having the caller call TryGetValue is that my  caller is a xaml binding.  (http://stackoverflow.com/q/13610137/16241)

Comment: TValue can't be int or byte because it is constrained to be a reference type.

Comment: @phoog only with the old code; not the second/non-working code