# Get object reference from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I have a little problem, below my code:

```
public class A
{
    public string ObjectA { get; set; }
}

public void Run()
{
    A a = new A();
    a.ObjectA = "Test number 1";

    BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    PropertyInfo myPropertyInfo = a.GetType().GetProperty("ObjectA", flags);
    object myNewObject = myPropertyInfo.GetValue(a);// Here should be reference

    a.ObjectA = "Test number 2";//After this line value myNewObject continued "Test number 1"
}
```

So my value **myNewObject** must be in output "Test number 2". Is there any way? It is this at all possible?

Comment: It's like a property with constraints doesn't it? I think that has been answered here? just my 2 cents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616161/why-cant-i-have-a-type-constraint-of-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong!

You're getting the string rather than the instance of `A` using reflection.

Changing `A.ObjectA` doesn't change the string reference. Actually, you're setting a different string to the backing string class field by the `ObjectA` property...

Auto-properties are syntactic sugar to avoid explicitly declaring class fields to properties which perform nothing when getting or setting their values:

```
// For example:
public string Text { get; set; }

// is...
private string _text;
public string Text { get { return _text; } set { _text = value; } }
```

Now turn your code into regular one (no reflection):

```
A a = new A();
a.ObjectA = "hello world";

object myNewObject = a.ObjectA;

// Do you think now that myNewObject should change...? :)
a.ObjectA = "goodbye";
```

> Is there any way? It is this at all possible?

No.

Maybe you can simulate this behavior using a `Func<T>`...

```
Func<object> myNewObjectGetter = () => myPropertyInfo.GetValue(a);
```

Now, whenever you call `myNewObjectGetter()` you're going to get the most fresh value of the whole property. BTW, this still doesn't address the impossible!

Comment: You're right, I chose the wrong example. In a moment I will change at closer to my problem

Comment: @MrLuk I believe that the underlying problem might be different enough to just end this Q&A by accepting some of answer we've already provided to you, and you can ask a different question. If you add a comment here to link me to the new question, I'll take a look at it...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way?

No. You can't put a reference to a property into an object variable. Such a variable can only hold a normal value, such as the string you put into it.

That answers the question as asked. You can clarify what you want to achieve and maybe we can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is no solution but I show some code

```
public class MyRows
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public object Val { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BasicDTO
{
    public int? Id { get; private set; }

    public PropertyInfo[] PropertyDTO;
    protected Type myType;

    public BasicDTO()
    {
        Load();
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        PropertyDTO = myType.GetProperties(flags);
    }
}

public class CustomerDTO : BasicDTO
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public CustomerDTO() { }

    protected override void Load()
    {
        myType = typeof(CustomerDTO);         
    }
}
```

Now my basic method

```
public void Run(BasicDTO dto)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = dto.PropertyDTO.Where(x => x.Name == "Surname").SingleOrDefault();
    MyRows mr = new MyRows();
    mr.Val = pi.GetValue(dto);//Here I need reference
}
```

When I change `CustomerDTO.Surname` my value `mr.Val` it must also be changed.
As I wrote above, it is probably impossible, but maybe anybody have a idea.

BTW: Value `mr.Val` I use only for binding (WPF). So maybe you have any other suggestions, how solve problem. I will be grateful for your help

Comment: You shouldn't provide an **answer** which doesn't answer your own issue!!!!!!!!!!!!! As I said you before, you should accept either my answer or other ones, and ask a new question copying and pasting this wrong answer...

Comment: Yes, I know. Thanks for help