# Dictionary than can return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have quite a few Dictionary Bindings in my code.  Most of them are not found and use a FallBackValue.

This all functions great for users.

However, when I run it in the debugger, it takes a very long time to show all those errors in the output window.

I asked this question [WPF Dictionary Binding failure is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13610137/16241) and was told that I should return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.

I have tried that, and it compiles.  But when I run it I get an exception.

**Is there any way to define a Dictionary that can also return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue?**  (Or some other way to fail faster.)

UPDATE: Here is an iteration what I tried:

```
public class NullTolerantDictionary<TKey, TValue> 
           : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> where TValue : class
{
    public new TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            bool success = TryGetValue(key, out value);
            if (success)
                return value;

            var errorResult = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue as TValue;

            if (errorResult != null)
                return errorResult;

            return default(TValue);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx) has a runtime type of Object, so errorResult is going to be null for any other TValue type, and `default(TValue)` is also null.  So in the end, you are typically returning null when the key is missing, rather than throwing the appropriate exception.  This is contrary to the IDictionary contract, which is why things don't work out.  In essence, your class looks like a real IDictionary (i.e. it implements IDictionary) but it is not really one (i.e. it doesn't behave like one).  You don't say what exception you get at runtime, but I assume it's a NullReferenceException from client code that is not expecting your method call to return null.

You are essentially trying to rewrite `dict[key]` as `dict.TryGetValue(key)` in existing code.  I can sympathize with the motives, but this won't work.  It has to be fixed from the calling side, and it sounds like you have no control over that.